# rewrite cck option values list using php

Tags: 6

I use finder module for Drupal 6. There is a possibility to rewrite cck select options list using php. In a cck field I have following options with values and names:

```
1|a
2|b
3|c
```

It doe's not matter what names I choose because finder module's default output is allways values. I need to rewrite the list, so names are outputted instead of values like this for example:

```
1|yes
2|no
3|dont know
```

Finder module made available following variables

```
$value - The themed display value of this option.
$key - The themed key value of this option.
$option - Object containing data that finder has about this option.
$finder_element - Object containing data about this finder element.
```

Can anybody help me with code, I hava absolutely no idea where to start. Thank you

Comment: For anyone interested I found a solution on issue list of finder module. Here is the link https://drupal.org/node/546844#comment-2821266